# How to pass some Order conditions in a method in c#

Tags: c#, func

I am creating a method to pass an optional predicate but in some cases I need to order the data filtered from this method. I dont know how can I pass order conditions with predicate itself or there is another way to do this ?

> But remember I need to pass ordering conditions dynamically because in different sections there are different ordering conditions

I would apply ordering conditions when I get the data from the method but as you can see in method there is AutoMapper doing its job to get only necessary properties from `TechArchiveNoSubsYpdcResult` model. And sometimes I need to order the data with properties from model `TechArchiveNoSubsYpdcResult` that are not included in `CompletedJobViewModel` model itself.

```
public IEnumerable<CompletedJobViewModel> GetCompletedJobsViewModels(Guid vesselId, int year, Func<TechArchiveNoSubsYpdcResult, bool> predicate = null)
    => Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CompletedJobViewModel>>(GetArchiveNoSubsYpdcResults(vesselId, year).OptionalWhere(predicate));
```

Does anybody know a way how to pass dynamically ordering conditions in a method ?

AutoMapper maps `TechArchiveNoSubsYpdcResult` to `CompletedJobViewModel`

I`m looking for something like this which looks like ordering 'predicate':

```
public IEnumerable<CompletedJobViewModel> GetCompletedJobsViewModels(Guid vesselId, int year, Func<TechArchiveNoSubsYpdcResult, bool> predicate = null, Order<Something> orderCondition = null)
    => Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CompletedJobViewModel>>(GetArchiveNoSubsYpdcResults(vesselId, year).OptionalWhere(predicate)).OptionalOrder(orderCondition);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to order by a single field, you can take a "key selector" function, like this:

```
public IEnumerable<CompletedJobViewModel> GetCompletedJobsViewModels<TKey>(Guid vesselId, int year, Func<TechArchiveNoSubsYpdcResult, bool> predicate = null, Func<TechArchiveNoSubsYpdcResult,TKey> keySelector = null) {
    var res = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CompletedJobViewModel>>(GetArchiveNoSubsYpdcResults(vesselId, year).OptionalWhere(predicate));
    if (keySelector != null) {
        res = res.OrderBy(keySelector);
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/nfRdzY)

Comment: what about if I have more than one field ? because in my situation I more than one field

Comment: @RajmondBurgaj Then you need a different approach altogether: you need to take many key selectors, and you need to make it non-generic returning IComparable.

Comment: since there is no other way around this situation I am accepting your answer as a correct one, thanks for your time :)